# sshdfilter and ipfw - why are my rules flushed so often?

Tags: macos, security, firewall

I have sshdfilter setup to maintain ipfw rules when someone is un invitedly trying to login my system. This has been working quite a while. Since a while - beginning to suspect the last lion upgrade (10.7.2) - I see sshdfilter adding rules and, when I check, I don't see the rules in ipfw using 'ipfw show'. When I add them manually, they show but again, after a while they are gone.
What I found in /var/log/system.log are messages like:

```
Nov  6 21:53:12 mac servermgrd[31448]: servermgr_ipfilter:ipfw config:Notice:Flushed IPv4 rules
Nov  6 21:53:12 mac servermgrd[31448]: servermgr_ipfilter:ipfw config:Notice:Flushed IPv6 rules
```

and I assume that after such a flush, my rules are in bit heaven.
How can I prevent my blocks are flushed?
My setup looks very familiar to [sshdfilter improvements](http://ronr.blogspot.com/2011/10/sshdfilter-improvements.html)

edit: In the meantime I changed sshdfilterrc to add the rules to /etc/ipfilter/ipfw.conf. This file is imported when the flush is executed. Disadvantage is that this file has to be maintained....

Comment: I thought I had got batpoop crazy seeing that stuff in my logs. I shall follow in your footsteps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change /etc/sshdfilterrc to add the rules to /etc/ipfilter/ipfw.conf. This file is imported when the flush is executed. Disadvantage is that this file has to be maintained....

This prevents the blocks staying in bit heaven when the flush comes along because this file is read after the flush is executed.

edit: on request added changes I made in /etc/sshdfilterrc

```
firewalladd='/sbin/ipfw add $idx deny all from $ip to any in; echo add $idx deny all from $ip to any in >> /etc/ipfilter/ipfw.conf;echo +`date` $ip >>/etc/ipfilter/sshdfilter_block.log'
firewalldel='/sbin/ipfw del $idx deny all from $ip to any in;grep -v " $ip ">/tmp/ipfw.conf;mv /tmp/ipfw.conf /etc/ipfilter/ipfw.conf;echo -`date` $ip >>/etc/ipfilter/sshdfilter_block.log'
```

this takes care of the block and the block Cancel actions, including some block.log to see when and how long an ip has been blocked.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to change sshdfilterrc?

Comment: edited the Answer with the modifications and a slight explanation. I hope it helps.